# Passing an IQueryable as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, iqueryable

I have a class which I want to pass a list of data to. I want this class to

1. return a list of vendors in the whole set of data
2. filter the data by a condition which I have as a parameter and return the filtered results as a second enumerable list.

I have added `IQueryable` condition as pseudo-code for what I would like to achieve. Is this possible?

```
internal class Problem
{
    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Class1> ReturnedData { get; set; }

    public Problem(List<Class1> data, IQueryable condition)
    {
        Vendors = data.SelectMany(d => d.Vendors).Select(v => v.VendorName).Distinct().Select(v => new Vendor {VendorName =  v}).ToList();

        ReturnedData = data.AsQueryable().Where(condition);
    }
}

internal class Class1
{
    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
    // lots of other stuff
}

internal class Vendor
{
    public object VendorName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will do slightly differently.

First install nuget package System.Linq.Dynamic

```
Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic
```

After that, 
`IQueryable 's Where function will support string as parameter. So you can do this:

```
protected static IQueryable<T> ApplyGridFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
            var qText = "id == 1";

            query = query.Where(qText);
            return query;
}
```

The benefit is that you can then build up the where condition in clientside easily without creating `Func<Class1, bool>>`

Answer (score 2):

When calling [`IQuerable<T>.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.90).aspx) as an extension method, the parameter that it takes is not the `IQueryable` instance, but rather a predicate expression:

```
public Problem(List<Class1> data, Expression<Func<Class1, bool>> condition)
{
    Vendors = data.SelectMany(d => d.Vendors).Select(v => v.VendorName).Distinct()
                  .Select(v => new Vendor {VendorName =  v}).ToList();

    ReturnedData = data.AsQueryable().Where(condition);
}
```

You can now create a variety of filters when you instantiate the `Problem` class:

```
var problemInstance = new Problem(data, x => x.VendorName == "Rob");
```

Comment: Well it does take an IQueryable as a parameter. The second parameter is the predicate.

Comment: @sturcotte06, while technically correct, this is because it is an extension method ON an IQueryable. It is rarely called directly and almost always as an extension method, which is exactly how the OP is calling it. As a result, the parameter that the correct overload would expect would be the predicate and the only time you would pass the IQueryable would be when invoking it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using just a delegate as input parameter and implement the filter logic in the calling class

```
    class Problem{
        public Problem(data, Func<data, IEnumerable<Class1>> delegate){
              ReturnedData = delegate(data);
        }
     }

var problem = new Problem(data, ds => ds.where(d => d.name =="xyz").tolist());
```